# My posts images and links are not correct when I publish my home page

Tags: permalinks

For my "https://eclipseglassesreview.com/" website: when I am in Elementor editing my home page, the posts images and links are correct. When I publish the home page, the posts images disappear and the links revert back to the home page.
I am using Themes (The Post Grid) to show my posts and have reset my permalinks several times with no luck.

Comment: It's next to impossible to properly answer this question without seeing the actual code used but my guess is that instead of using the `$post->ID` for each of the posts, it's reverting the `$post_id` for the home page. As an expirement, add a featured image to the home page and see if that shows up for each post. (Probably will if all the links are going back to the home page.)  That said you'll probably have to ask the Theme and Plugin developers for guidance as to why this is happening and how to properly use the widget.